# Best practice to invalidate cache data after application updated

Tags: ios, caching

I have an iOS application and release it two times. For better understanding, let's refer to the first release as `V1` and second release as `V2`.

There is a UITableView display a list of events fetched from the server. For better user experience and performance I will cache the events download from the server. So next time the user enters the app I can show a list of events immediately with cached data instead of a loading indicator.

`V1` app: The table view cell is configured with an event which is an NSDictionay and get the name property like this:

```
// Get the event name
NSString *name = [event objectForKey:@"name"];
```

`V2` app: After event getting more complicated I decide to create a dedicated model for the event, let's call it `Event` and get the name property like this:

```
// Get the event name directly from Event model name property
NSString *name = event.name
```

After releasing `V2`, here comes the problem.

**This `V2` app crashes because it tries to read the name property from an event dictionary which is cached by `V1` app**

My question is what strategy or best practice to invalidate cached data. Some methods come to my mind but they all have flaws.

**1) Clean all cached data on every release.**
This is the most safer way no matter how our program differs from last version app. But throw away all the cached data may be overreacting.

**2) Write more code to check if need to ignore cached data.**
Taking the `V2` app of mine as an example. I may write code to check the cached event data like this to ensure everything is fine.

```
// Validation code in V2 app

if ([cachedEvent isKindOfClass:Event.calss]) {
    NSString *name = cached.name;
    // other code
} else {
    // Ignore the cached event and fetch event from server
}
```

This method works but sometimes `isKindOfClass` is not enough, you have to write more and more validation code. I can see it will become very troublesome to check every cached data.

Love to hear your thoughts and ways to do it, Thanks in advance.